# RTCVideoCapturer capturerWithDeviceName:(NSString*) becomes very slow after subsequent calls

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios8, webrtc

I'm building a `webrtc` based `voip` app. I call the following code before each call I make:

```
NSMutableArray *m = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *o = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

//[m addObject:[[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"maxFrameRate" value:@"30"]];
//[m addObject:[[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"maxFrameRate" value:@"24"]];
//[m addObject:[[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"maxHeight" value:@"180"]];
NSString* cameraID = nil;
for (AVCaptureDevice *captureDevice in [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo]) {
    if (captureDevice.position == AVCaptureDevicePositionFront) {
        cameraID = [captureDevice localizedName];
        break;
    }
}

capturer = [RTCVideoCapturer capturerWithDeviceName:cameraID]; //why so slow :(

RTCMediaConstraints *videoConstraints = [[RTCMediaConstraints alloc] initWithMandatoryConstraints:m optionalConstraints:o];
videoSource = [peerConnectionFactory videoSourceWithCapturer:capturer constraints:videoConstraints];

localVideoTrack = [peerConnectionFactory videoTrackWithID:@"ARDAMSv0" source:videoSource];

lms = [peerConnectionFactory mediaStreamWithLabel:@"ARDAMS"];

if (localVideoTrack) [lms addVideoTrack:localVideoTrack];
[lms addAudioTrack:[peerConnectionFactory audioTrackWithID:@"ARDAMSa0"]];

[peerConnection addStream:lms constraints:[[RTCMediaConstraints alloc] init]];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [callViewController setLocalVideo];
});
```

After the call ends I reset all these variables (mostly just set them to nil). I've seen this approach work very well, but recently a bug has sneaked in there. Every subsequent call increases the execution time of this line

```
capturer = [RTCVideoCapturer capturerWithDeviceName:cameraID];
```

I tried setting the capturer just once at the start of the app, but then the app crashes on

```
videoSource = [peerConnectionFactory videoSourceWithCapturer:capturer constraints:videoConstraints];
```

even though all parameters are initialized (I checked using the debugger).

Does anybody have an idea as to what this could be? I'm sure this same code worked perfectly before. I did not update the `webrtc` library, `xcode` or `iOS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track!

What you need to do instead is create not only the capturer in the beginning, but videosource, localvideotrack, localaudiostream, and RTCMediaStream object. Once localvideotrack and localaudiostream are created, add em to a RTCMediaStream object that's available class wide. Then, when you want to start a conversation, all you'll need to do is reuse the RTCMediaStream object you've created in the beginning by adding it to a new peerconnection! Just be sure to kill the peerconnection object when conversation is done. Nothing needs to be done at that time to RTCMediaStream object.

The reason why things are getting so slow is that each time you create a new capturer, it doesn't appropriately kill off any previous instances that might already be about.

Comment: Thankk you for the tips, I have a few days off now, but I'll look into it when I get back to work.

Comment: Sorry about taking so long, my code was a mess so I decided to rewrite large parts of it. I'm reusing everything except the peerconnection now, but the app crashes when I call [peerConnection close]; Do you have any idea why that might be?

Comment: What's the error you're getting? Is the peer connection nil? Also check peer connection status to see if it's not already closed for some reason (in this case, would be peerConnection.signalingState).

Comment: I wasn't really getting an error, just an EXC_BAD_ACCESS somewhere in the underlying OpenGL code. I removed the local and remote video views from the main view before closing the call, and now it no longer crashes. The last problem I still have is that after a few calls (say 5 or 6) I get "failed to create framebuffer object 8cdd" spammed in my log.